# Make Visual Studio 2017 Diagnostic Tools event window autofit

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, diagnostic-tools

In Visual Studio 2017 how do I make the "Events" window auto fit the "Event" column. I open it in full screen by default however it always squishes it up and I manually have to autofit the column.

Is there a solution other than manually resizing it every single time?

There is a lot of useful information that I often miss as the size means I don't read it unless I go actively looking for it.

[image]

Comment: Could you vote that feature request?

Comment: Appreciate you making the request. Voted and accepted your answer as there is no real "answer" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result as yours, it will go back to the previous Event column size if we debug it again, it doesn't like other VS windows, we could change it and use it as we want to.

But I agree with you, it would be a better feature request to the product team, I submitted it here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/20167612-make-visual-studio-2017-diagnostic-tools-event-win

If possible, you could vote and add your comment there. The product team will view this feature request and share us the feedback if it gets enough votes.